# Proof verification of if $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_n$ is bounded then $\{x_n\}$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and: 
>   $$
> S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_n
> $$
>   Given $\{S_n\}$ is a bounded sequence prove that $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence.

Similar questions have been asked here several times but all of them are in the context of series. I'm looking for a precalculus proof of boundedness of $x_n$.

Consider the following cases for $n$:

$$
S_1 = x_1 \\
S_2 = x_1 + x_2 \\
\dots \\
S_n = x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n
$$

For some given $n$ we know that $S_n$ is a number. It gives that:
$$
|S_1| = M_1\\
|S_2| = M_2 \\
\dots \\
|S_n| = M_n
$$

Now since $\{S_n\}$ is bounded by some value it gives that:
$$
\{ \forall k \le n: |S_k| \le M = \max\{M_1, M_2, \dots,M_n\} \} \\
$$
Now take $S_n$ and $S_{n-1}$ and subtract them:

$$
|S_{n} - S_{n-1}| = |x_n|
$$

Since both $S_n$ and $S_{n-1}$ are less than or equal to some $M$:
$$
|S_n - S_{n-1}| = |x_n| = |S_n + (-S_{n-1})| \le |S_n| + |-S_{n-1}| \le 2M
$$

Therefore $|x_n| < 2M$ and hence bounded.

**Questions:**

1. Is my proof valid?
2. I feel like i have mixed precalculus concepts with concepts related to series (which are mostly considered in Calculus II), have I?

Comment: Given $n$, $S_n$ is a *number*. It makes no sense to say that it is bounded. If you mean that the *sequence* $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded, then you have a bound for the sequence: $|S_n|\le M$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: That last bit with $|x_n| \leq 0$ is incorrect. How did you come to that conclusion? Were you perhaps falsely interpreting the triangle inequality for $|S_n - S_{n-1}|$? That would be $|S_n - S_{n-1}| = |S_n +\left(- S_{n-1}\right)| \leq |S_n| + |-S_{n-1}| \leq 2M$. Anyway, this is kind of superseded by the comment above, but it's still an area of your reasoning that you should examine.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thank you for your comment. I've updated question section to make it more clear.

Comment: @SamStreeter Thank you for taking your time. You are right, I've used the triangle inequality in a wrong way. updated the post so hopefully now it makes more sense.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you for you comment. Wouldn't that require calculus concepts? In particular limits which i would like to keep away from for this problem.

Comment: My comment didn't require calculus, but I needed that $\{S_n\}$ converged, not that the sequence was bounded.